# change a content/variable at a later time in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i tried looking at capture, yield, content_for don't think any of these is the solution.

i'm trying to create a reports, calculating and looping column by column, row by row.

But i need to display an average for each of the column, but i will not be able to calculate the average not until i have the totals for each of my rows.

by the time I have finished showing all the totals, the HTML table has been rendered. now without using Javascript, is there anything i can do like a "placeholder" that i can put in the table that i can reference and at a later stage?

Comment: can you add source of controller and html.erb files?

Comment: just want to do something like this:
<% variable_to_be_filled_out_later %$>

# at some point later in the view

<% variable_to_be_filled_out_later %?

so im trying to achieve something like that.

Comment: it can be done without "placeholders", if you add your code I'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do these calculations in the view. I would suggest doing it in the controller looping through your data. Try keeping out heavy calculations from views.

Comment: i am but at this point, i just want to do it this way. if anyone has an idea please let me know.